# MS Access: After I select multiple values from a list box, I want those values to then disappear from my options

Tags: ms-access

I want to be able to select multiple values for one field on a table (from a list on another table) and then when I go to the next item, I want the options I already picked to disappear from the list.

It seems like a simple thing to do. Is that something I would need a query for? I'm not sure how to write/use those just yet. [Quick example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4Crs.png)

Sorry I can't embed images yet. I made a quick example of what I want it to do. I want the form to ignore the "940" choice because it has already been entered into another "check." How would I write that in a query? I'm familiar with how to make simple ones but I don't know how to code yet for it.

Comment: Are you using multi-value field? Edit question to show sample data and table relationship.  Yes, query is needed.

Comment: Play around with the pieces to start.  Make a table, use create form on that table to make a form.  Add a listbox and a button to the form.  Set the listbox multi-select property to true and load all the listbox values from that other table.  At that point we don't know what you want to do when you hit the button.  But after doing it update the end of the button click event and add code to  change the listbox's record source to exclude the values you selected and unselect all items.